# Why do i have this error? Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to do a search in google using a free proxy server. Here is my code:

```
string SearchResults = "http://google.com/search?q=" + textBox1.Text.Trim();
HttpWebRequest request;
HttpWebResponse response;
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SearchResults);
request.Method = "GET";      
request.Proxy= new WebProxy("http://209.150.146.27:8080", true);
//here is the issue
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

What can i do in order to fix this problem?
I use this list of proxy servers:
[www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Transparent](http://www.gatherproxy.com/proxylist/anonymity/?t=Transparent)

[image]

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace of the exception? And values in the Response and Status properties of the exception - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx:  If a WebException is thrown, use the Response and Status properties of the exception to determine the response from the server.

Comment: There is no full stack, only this line of error that i mentioned in the title. Now, as far as the value is concerned, i cannot print it because the error lies there. any other suggestion? thank you for your time

Comment: I am not sure that we can help you without information from Response and Status fields of the exception. And full error message from the exception would also be of great use. In any case, have you tried to make a request without Proxy? Or to another host?

Comment: Well, without proxy the request and the response works absolutely fine. In any host i have the same error. How can i post the values of the response if i cannot print them with Console.WriteLIne? I can use debug for this?

Comment: At worst case you can just put a breakpoint in the catch block that captures that exception and manually read those properties. Or use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx - it should write to the Debug pane in visual studio if you are debugging the application from it.

Comment: i posted a screenshot, can you please tell what to expand for you to see?

Comment: There are a lot of information on how to do it  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with proxy server.
It's returning 503 error code or just not available.
When I'm removing `request.Proxy= new WebProxy("http://209.150.146.27:8080", true);` everything is working.
When I use another public proxy server everything is working too.
Example of refactored code with new proxy server and try-catch:

```
var searchResults = "http://google.com/search?q=" + textBox1.Text.Trim();

HttpWebResponse response = null;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchResults);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://92.46.122.98:3128", true);

try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Proxy server is probably do not working. Error message: "+ex.Message);
}

if (response != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Job done!");
}
```

Comment: i used your example and it works fine for me ass well. thank you for this. where did you find your proxy server?

Comment: What proxy type you choose? and what about anonymity? I marked it as green! (correct answer)

Comment: HTTP only. Any privacy.